# install selenium webdriver in debain 6.0.1 amazon EC2 instances

Tags: java, maven, selenium, amazon-ec2

installing selenium in Debian

http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp

i am following this link

i created the pom.xml
then install jdk and jre
and then installed apache maven

when i try this command

```
   mvn clean install
```

it gives me an error

```
  root@debian:/var/www/sele_webd# mvn clean install
  Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
  We cannot execute /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.i686/bin/java
```

how can i solve it ..

or else is there any other easy tutorial to install selenium webdriver in debain 6.0.1

after thryin this link i am getting this new error

```
                    root@debian:~# mvn install
        [WARNING]
        [WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective settings
        [WARNING] Unable to parse element 'port', must be an integer (position: END_TAG seen ...<port>port_number</port>... @7:31) caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "port_number" @ /root/.m2/settings.xml, line 7, column 31
        [WARNING]
        [INFO] Scanning for projects...
        [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
        [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
        [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
        [INFO] Total time: 0.092 s
        [INFO] Finished at: 2014-03-25T21:11:57-07:00
        [INFO] Final Memory: 2M/15M
        [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
        [ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (/root). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory. -> [Help 1]
        [ERROR]
        [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
        [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
        [ERROR]
        [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
        [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluen
```

Comment: It might be an issue with your environment variables. What is JAVA_HOME set as.

Comment: how can i check wht it is set to i tried echo $JAVA_HOME but it prints a blank line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check Your JAVA_HOME variable is configured correctly. Set up guide for Java Home using Linux http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-set-java_home-path-variable/

Here is a link regarding Amazon EC2 and Java Home http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/the-enterprise-cloud/how-to-use-the-command-line-with-amazons-ec2-api-tools/5574/#.

Comment: Thanks for the replay @Lt_Shade. but i am using debain(linux) operating system

Comment: I put a link in for how to configure it with Linux

Comment: this link helped me alot  http://mshsoftware.com/site/kb/set-java-home-on-linux.html   .. thanks for the help

Comment: but i have got some new error can u just help with wht the error is about

Comment: Looks like your port number isn't getting set to a int and is remaining a string. You could try manually setting the port number in your code.